# Mongo DB installation on RHEL 5.11 x64

Tags: mongodb, installation, rhel5

I am trying to install MongoDB 3.0.0 on one of the sandbox which has RHEL Linux 5.11 64bit

I was able to download all the packages using yum command mentioned in the official document here [MongoDB Installation](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/?_ga=1.169401961.955000207.1426105937).

I am trying to run following command as per the documentation

```
semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017
```

and it is giving me below error.

```
/usr/sbin/semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017
libsepol.context_from_record: type mongod_port_t is not defined
libsepol.context_from_record: could not create context structure
libsepol.port_from_record: could not create port structure for range 27017:27017 (tcp)
libsepol.sepol_port_modify: could not load port range 27017 - 27017 (tcp)
libsemanage.dbase_policydb_modify: could not modify record value
libsemanage.semanage_base_merge_components: could not merge local modifications into policy
/usr/sbin/semanage: Could not add port tcp/27017
```

I have root access on this sandbox but I am really clueless what this means. How can I install MongoDB successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Configure the package management system(yum)

```
Sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.4.
```

so that you can install   MongoDB directly, using yum.

Use the following repository file:

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-
org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc
```

Step 2: Use the below command to install MongoDB

```
Sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

Step 3:Start Mongod Service

```
Sudo service mongod start
```

Step 4: Then start Mongo with the command below

```
Mongo
```

Now Create your database as use

And then start building collections and insert documents into in the collection

For More detail vist https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Answer (score -1):

By default this port is already authorized:

```
#### # semanage port -l | grep mongod_port_t
mongod_port_t  tcp      **27017**-27019, 28017-28019
```